# How can move/use one element at different position? In Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

```
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.addtocart" as="product.info.stock.sku.old"/>
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.stock.sku.additional"/>
```

I have tried the above code in `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml` file and getting as

```
<?=$block->getChildHtml('product.info.stock.sku.old',true);?>
<?=$block->getChildHtml('product.info.stock.sku.additional',true);?>
```

But only one work at a time, actually I want to move sku in simple product which has options or not.

Comment: in which page you need to move elements

Comment: single product page but its done by such method given by @Sander Jongsma But If you have better answer so, you can post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not move one element to 2 positions. It doesn't have a clone function or somethings. So in order to do this you will need to create a second block for this, like:

```
<container name="product.info.stock.sku.copy" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku.copy" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

Use other names to avoid collisions.

Comment: Thanks, But i already did with method like you suggest. I supposed cloning is exist in magento 2.